# Instanciating many templates in constexpr function

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I am working on a GameBoy emulator. Out of curiosity, I want to generate an array of `constexpr` `Opcode` objects that  contain a `run()` function pointer among some other useful fields.

Here's an example of how it roughly would work like:

```
#include <array>

struct CPU
{
    int some_state = 0;
};

void f(CPU& cpu)
{
    cpu.some_state = 42;
}

void g(CPU& cpu)
{
    cpu.some_state = 12;
}

struct Opcode
{
    using Runner = void(*)(CPU&);
    Runner run = [](CPU&) {};

    /* more fields here */
};

constexpr auto gen_opcodes()
{
    std::array<Opcode, 2> ret {};

    ret[0] = { f };
    ret[1] = { g };

    return ret;
}

constexpr auto opcodes = gen_opcodes();

int main()
{
    CPU cpu;
    opcodes[1].run(cpu);
}
```

The reason for the array to be `constexpr` is that I want it to be well optimized by the compiler. In my understanding, if the array was only `const` it would be way harder for the compiler to optimize away the `run()` calls, as those are called individually in such a way the compiler should inline them, i.e. `if (something == 0x00) { opcodes[0x00].run(blahblah); }`.

However, the interest of this approach is to generate a bunch of `opcodes` at once. I thought of using template functions, as some `opcodes` come into a pattern, I should easily be able to generate tens of `opcodes` at once!

But while the following works:

```
template<int i>
void f(CPU& cpu)
{
    cpu.some_state = i;
}

/* ... */

constexpr auto gen_opcodes()
{
    std::array<Opcode, 2> ret {};

    ret[0] = { f<3> };
    ret[1] = { f<2> };

    return ret;
}
```

This fails:

```
constexpr auto gen_opcodes()
{
    std::array<Opcode, 100> ret {};

    for (int i = 30; i < 50; ++i)
    {
        ret[i] = { f<i> };
    }

    return ret;
}
```

NB: This is obviously for the sake of the example, it's slightly different in practice.

The reason is that `i` in this context is not a constant expression.

**How would one generate those function templates without writing them by hand?** Otherwise is there a different solution that is "short enough" and has the advantages I was talking about earlier?

I had some ideas but none seems to be sufficient:

- Stateful lambdas. However `std::function` does not work in a `constexpr` context because it has a non-trivial destructor and capturing lambdas can't cast into a function pointer.
- Function objects. I don't know how I would store them in that way in a `constexpr` context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason is that i in this context is not a constant expression

So the trick is transform `i` in a constant expression.

You are using the `std::array`'s `operator[]` in a `constexpr` function, so you're using C++17.

With C++17 you can use `std::index_sequence`/`std::make_index_sequence` (available starting from C++14) and template folding (from C++17).

So you can write `gen_opcodes()` in two steps.

A first step that generate a `std::index_sequence` with the length of your loop

```
constexpr auto gen_opcodes_1()
{ return gen_opcodes_2(std::make_index_sequence<20U>{}); }
```

and a second step that uses template folding to simulate the for-loop

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto gen_opcodes_2 (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 {
   std::array<Opcode, 100> ret {};

   ( (ret[30+Is] = { f<30+Is> }), ... );

   return ret;
 }
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <array>

struct CPU
 { int some_state = 0; };

template <int I>
void f (CPU & cpu)
 { cpu.some_state = I; }

struct Opcode
 { 
   using Runner = void(*)(CPU&);
   Runner run = [](CPU&) {};
 };

template <std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto gen_opcodes_2 (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 {
   std::array<Opcode, 100> ret {};

   ( (ret[30+Is] = { f<30+Is> }), ... );

   return ret;
 }

constexpr auto gen_opcodes_1()
 { return gen_opcodes_2(std::make_index_sequence<20U>{}); }

constexpr auto opcodes = gen_opcodes_1();

int main()
 {
   CPU cpu;
   opcodes[1].run(cpu);
 }
```